# How to aggregate calibration curves which were created in cross validation?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, calibration, isotonic, sigmoid-curve

When looking into Scikit's [CalibratedClassifierCV](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a243d9633/sklearn/calibration.py#L30) I noticed that the object needs to [keep multiple calibrated classifiers](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a243d9633/sklearn/calibration.py#L223) in memory to average the results in real time.

[image]

I understand that these classifiers have each been trained on part of the dataset, in order to ensure calibration is done on a disjunct training set, which is definitely a good idea.

The down side of keeping 3 classifiers around and bagging them is that it lowers model interpretability, and increases the complexity (and possibly compute time).

Question: is there any reason why after the calibration curves have been fit (be they isotonic or sigmoids) the original classifier can't be fit on the entire training set, and the calibration curves averaged out?

[image]